# Migrating components from Delphi 7 to XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-7

I have an old application built on `Delphi 7` which has a large number of Custom 3rd party components. I need to migrate it to `XE2`. I have the `.dcu` files of the custom components and for some components I have source too.

Is there any way to include those `.dcu` files in my `Delphi XE2` code.

Comment: there are two delphi decompilation projects, whic hmay help you to re-create sources for those components, so if you have no other choice - youccan try it. But only as last resort. Really last.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use .dcu files from one version of Delphi in a different version. You need to re-compile from source.

However, that's much easier said than done. Because of the Unicode changes introduced in Delphi 2009 your components will almost surely not work when re-compiled in the latest version of Delphi. You'll need to get updated source for all the components. What's more you'll need to update your code too.

The starting point is Marco Cantù's [white paper on Unicode](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38980).

Comment: "Big Bang Integration" here you come.